# Syntax error come at the time of mongodb module installation at Drupal 8

Tags: php, mongodb, drupal-8

Syntax error come at the time of mongodb module installation at Drupal 8.

Error came from modules\contrib\mongodb\modules\mongodb_watchdog\src\Logger.php

```
 protected function countCollection(Collection $collection, array $selector = []): int {
    if (version_compare(MongoDb::libraryVersion(), '1.4.0') >= 0) {
      return $collection->countDocuments($selector);
    }
    else {
      return $collection->count($selector);
    }
  }
```

> protected function countCollection(Collection $collection, array
>   $selector = []): int {

This line make an error

> Error: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ';' or '{' in
>   C:\wamp64\www\d8_demo\modules\contrib\mongodb\modules\mongodb_watchdog\src\Logger.php, line 153

I am using PHP 7.1.9 and mongodb 4.2.1

I have no idea about

> protected function somemethod(): int {